# 690 VAC transient step causes ringing on secondary of step down transformer

Tags: transformer, noise, mains, resonance

I have an issue in a 50 Hz 690 VAC mains system, where external noise by some external thyristor equipment causes a quick dip on the main line voltage (blue line in image). And this dip causes a ringing on the secondary side of a 690 VAC to 24 VAC transformer as seen in the image (green line).

The resonance is quite noticeable, it also rings at about 8 kHz! I don't have enough capacitance and inductance on the secondary side in circuit elements to contribute to this ringing! One line is terminated to a board ground with some nF EMC capacitor termination to chassis ground, the other line to high impedance (>100k) and line to line is about 5 kohm. This is a voltage mode transformer.

Is the transformer winding capacitance resonating towards the grid inductances here? Anyone have ideas and suggestions.

[image: Waveform]

[image: Transient and resonance]

[image: Equivelant Circuit]

The measurements were made with differential isolated probes connected to a floating battery powered power supply.

Comment: You should post a schematic showing part numbers and have data sheet references to the parts used especially the transformer. Also show a full cycle waveform and show how you connect your probles.

Comment: The transformer is a custom made part from one of our suppliers. We do not have a detailed datasheet.

Comment: It's needed @stonie <-- if it's custom made for you then you will have details of what was made (as per quality control and design control).

Comment: The measurements were made with differential isolated probes. The oscilloscope a floating battery powered oscilloscope.

Comment: What causes the transient? How does that circuit look?

Comment: Unknown, this is a mains grid in a site where our equipment is installed. But from the waveform and periodicity it can be deduced its a thyristor based switching equipment that causes the 690V noise step.

Comment: Which points on your circuit did the differential probe connect?

Comment: Primary of the transformer. The secondary side measurement shown here was by the secondary on the transformer. There is a 1 meter long shielded signal cable (floating transformer side, chassis grounded PCB side) to the PCB. Noise exists with or without the shielded cable. Other secondary side measurements were made by the end point and filtered by the zero crossing detector inputs. It was the same or filtered version of the same signal. So the signal (but filtered) is consistent all the way to the sensing point.

Comment: Same results on the PCB side with a normal single ended probe and the oscilloscope floating on battery power.

Comment: Hmm. How about a Zobel link at 8 kHz?

Comment: More info at [Zobel derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobel_network).

Comment: There are many solutions possible to tolarate this i think, but i am most interested in understanding how this resonance happens. What elements are involved.